# jQuery XML traversal of child using .each()

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml to output in a div but i'm having trouble with the child.

What am I doing wrong? I have to parse it without modifying the xml.

**Expected Output:**

Member 1

Hobbies: 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 1

Member 2

Hobbies: 
-Hobby 2 
-Hobby 2 
-Hobby 2

**Actual Output:**

Member 1

Hobbies: 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 2 
-Hobby 2 
-Hobby 2

Member 2

Hobbies: 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 1 
-Hobby 2 
-Hobby 2 
-Hobby 2

**XML:**

```
 <members>
  <person>
    <name>Member 1</name>
    <hobbies>
     <hobby>Hobby 1</hobby>
     <hobby>Hobby 1</hobby>
     <hobby>Hobby 1</hobby>
    </hobbies>
   </person>
   <person>
   <name>Member 2</name>
   <hobbies>
     <hobby>Hobby 2</hobby>
     <hobby>Hobby 2</hobby>
     <hobby>Hobby 2</hobby>
   </hobbies>
</person>
```

**Code:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('person').each(function(){
        $('.members').append(
          '<div class="person">' +
          '<h2>' + $(this).find('name').text() + '</h2>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<h3>Hobbies:</h3>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<ul class="hobbies">' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<br />'
           )
        });

        $(xml).find('hobbies').children().each(function () {
          $('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>').appendTo('.hobbies')
        });
       }
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: You want to look into using an HTML templating library. For example: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop to find hobbies is finding both `<hobbies>` nodes of your xml. You need to be more specific. You can do this by referencing the element you are accessing in your `.each` loop:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      // In your callback, name the reference to index and element
      $(xml).find('person').each(function(num, elem){
        $('.members').append(
          '<div class="person">' +
          '<h2>' + $(this).find('name').text() + '</h2>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<h3>Hobbies:</h3>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<ul class="hobbies">' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<br />'
        );

        // only find the hobbies node of this element, not whole xml
        $(elem).find('hobbies').children().each(function () {
          $('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>').appendTo('.hobbies')
        });
      });


    }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: When i try that i get elem undefined?

Comment: I made a mistake - the `$(elem)` part is meant to be inside the `.each` callback. I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need find it's current children only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('person').each(function(){
        $('.members').append(
          '<div class="person">' +
          '<h2>' + $(this).find('name').text() + '</h2>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<h3>Hobbies:</h3>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<ul class="hobbies">' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<br />' +
          '<br />'
           )

           $(this).find('hobbies').children().each(function () {
                $('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>').appendTo('.hobbies')
            });
        });
       }
      });
    });
```

Comment: is there a documentation on how to do that?